# Grep is messing up my understanding

Tags: regex, grep

For sometime I have been trying to play with grep to retrieve data from files and I noticed something funny.

It might be my ignorance but here is what happens...

Suppose I have a file ABC. the data is:

```
a
abc
ab
bac
bb
ac
```

Now ran this grep command,

```
grep a* ABC
```

I found the output to contain lines starting a with b.c. why is this happening?

Comment: man grep + learn regular expressions + enable grep colored output…

Comment: What were you expecting to happen?

Comment: Posting from my phone so I can't post much. Well try posing an image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used 'a*' as your search pattern... the '*' means ZERO or MORE of the previous character, so 'b.c' matches, having ZERO or more 'a's in it.

On a semi-related note, I'd recommend quoting the 'a*' bit, since if you have ANY files in the current subdirectory which start with a, you'll be VERY surprised to see what you're really searching for, since the shell (bash,zsh,csh,sh,dash,wtfsh...) will perform wildcard expansion automatically BEFORE the command is executed.

if you want to search for lines which START with 'a', then you'll need to anchor the search pattern with a leading ^ character, so your pattern becomes '^a*', but again, the * means ZERO or more, so it's not useful in this situation where you only have one letter... use '^a' instead.

As a contrived example, if you wanted to find all the lines containing a 'c' AND those containing the letters 'bc', then you could use 'b*c' as the search pattern... meaning ZERO or more b's, and a c.

The power of the regex search pattern is immense, and takes some time to grok.  Peruse the man pages for grep(1), regex(7), pcre(3), pcresyntax(3), pcrepattern(3).

Once you get the hang of them, regex's are useful in sed, grep, perl, vim, (probably emacs too), ... uh, it's late (early?) nothing more comes to mind, but they're VERY powerful.

As some bonus, '*' means ZERO or more, '+' means ONE or more, and '?' means ZERO or ONE.

So to search for things with two or more a's... 'aa+', which is 1 a, and 1+ a (1 or more)

I ramble.... (regex(7)!)

Comment: http://i599.photobucket.com/albums/tt71/shouvik/Infosys%20campus/IMG_20110917_170312.jpg sorry for posting an image.don't have computer access with net. Could you explain why deopak is not printed

Comment: your search pattern is 'de*pak'.  * doesn't work like on windows, it's not a 'anything here', it means ZERO or more of the PREVIOUS character.  So you're searching for depak, dpak, deeeepak, and so on.  no 'o' in that pattern, so deopak isn't found.  If you want your search to catch deopak, try 'de*o*pak', which means d,zero or more e's, zero or more o's, p, a, k.    Does that help?

Comment: Oh okay, thanks... :) answer accepted. man grep was not much help

Comment: nah, the grep man page is more of a jumping off point to find regex(7) and the pcre pages.  There's a program named 'visual-regexp' available on my Debian system which I've played with a while ago, lets you tinker with patterns to see how they match things, there's also some good demonstrations of regex's on the web (when you get web access).  Glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

grep tries to find that pattern in the whole line. Use `^a` to get line starting with `a` or `^a*$` to find lines containing only `a`s (including the empty line).

also, please quote that shell argument (eg: `'^a*$'`), if you use `a*` and there is a file in the working directory starting with an `a` you will get very weird results...

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works for me. The `^` means beginning of a line - so it has to start with `a`.

```
grep ^a ABC
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put quotes around your pattern:

```
grep "a*" ABC
```

Otherwise the `*` is interpreted by the shell (which does wild-card filename matching), instead of by `grep` itself.

Comment: I think he needs only lines that start with `a`, this will return every line which contains `a`. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @Tom: It's not clear what he wants.  But his original `grep` statement is certainly never going to do the right thing!

Comment: Note, however, that if the current directory doesn't contain any files beginning with `a`, the `a*` argument will be passed to `grep` untouched.

Comment: @Oli It's not clear but I assume it from the last sentence. But you're right, without to quotes it's not going to work.